# Disable Chrome console "Auto Completion" of commands

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am learning web development and make use of chrome devTools a lot. However on "console" I want to disable autocompletion feature, e.g. when I type window.locat.. then it automatically gives me hint about window.location. I want that to be disabled since I feel while learning it is good not to get prompts in order to remember all the properties of objects.

Any idea how to do it?

Help is appreciated!